# Proper usage of REJECT method in Ruby on Rails -- help me convert many lines into Ruby one-liner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashed names and emails, like this:

```
array = [{"email"=>"test@test.com", "name"=>"Test"},
      {"email"=>"testA@gmail.com", "name"=>"Test A"},
      {"name"=>"Test B", "email"=>"testB@test.com"},
      {"email"=>"testC@yahoo.com", "name"=>"Test C"},
      {"name"=>"Test D", "email"=>"testD@hotmail.com"},
      {"email"=>"testE@test.com"},
      {"name"=>"Test F", "email"=>"testF@test.com"}]
```

I want to filter out certain emails in a "blacklist" array.  The following works, but it's too verbose.

```
 blacklist = ["@test.com", "@gmail.com"] 
 na = array
 blacklist.each do |b|
   na = na.reject{ |e| e["email"].include?(b) }
 end

 # na => [{"email"=>"testC@yahoo.com", "name"=>"Test C"}, {"name"=>"Test D", "email"=>"testD@hotmail.com"}]
```

Can someone help me by putting this into a sexy Ruby one-liner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One more suggestion :)

```
array.reject { |h| blacklist.any? { |b| h["email"].include? b } }
```

Comment: You could do that, but why add the extra block?

Comment: like it , but instead of ".include? b " , i will prefer ".ends_with? b" in this particular case , because that is what the intention of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
people.reject { |p| blacklist.include?("@" + p["email"].split("@", 2)[1]) }
```

Note that you should build the `blacklist` as a set to make the inclussion test O(1).

```
require 'set'
blacklist = ["@test.com", "@gmail.com"].to_set
```

Comment: Cool. I wasn't familiar with `to_set`. Interesting.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  All three solutions worked. I ran 5000 iterations and averaged their speed (e.g., run-time).  They are all fairly close (at most 1e-05 second difference), but @WarHog's solution seems to be the fastest on average (1.41e-05).  It's also the one that requires least amount of tinkering with my existing code.

Answer (score 1):

If this hash is coming from the DB, then you should do the filtering on the DB side.

If not, then don't run a separate `reject` for each blacklist item. You probably want something like

```
array.reject {|rec| blacklist.include? "@#{rec['email'].split('@').last}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [{"email"=>"test@test.com", "name"=>"Test"},
      {"email"=>"testA@gmail.com", "name"=>"Test A"},
      {"name"=>"Test B", "email"=>"testB@test.com"},
      {"email"=>"testC@yahoo.com", "name"=>"Test C"},
      {"name"=>"Test D", "email"=>"testD@hotmail.com"},
      {"email"=>"testE@test.com"},
      {"name"=>"Test F", "email"=>"testF@test.com"}]

blacklist = ["test.com", "gmail.com"] 
na = array.reject { |e| blacklist.include?(e["email"].split('@').last) }

=> [{"name"=>"Test C", "email"=>"testC@yahoo.com"}, {"name"=>"Test D", "email"=>"testD@hotmail.com"}]
```